# video processing with opencv

Tags: video, image-processing, opencv, background-subtraction

i'm trying to detect car in a video file.i can do background subtraction and the moving cars are visible as foreground object. but i can't draw rectangle around the car. how can i do it?

or how can i say in a particular area of the frame there is a car/or there is no car now.please help.

Comment: The link above no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to draw lines, circles, poligons, etc., you should use the [drawing functions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.htm) that OpenCV has to help you in this case.

So, (for instance) once you've found each object in the image, look for its center and then draw an ellpise around it.